# Eclipse on linux, c project

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, build, project

I have a little problem with eclipse (Indigo, Luna) on Linux.

Every time when I create a new c project and try to build it, I receive this errors:

> **Description Resource    Path    Location    Type**
>   **make: *** **[test3] Error 1 test3**         **C/C++ Problem****
>   **undefined reference to `main'   test3           C/C++ Problem**

To resolve this I need to restart eclipse and build all. But I don't wont to restart IDE every time when I'm creating a new project.

Are there some solution for this?

OBS: With Java all is fine.

Comment: Use a different IDE? like [geany](http://www.geany.org/)

Comment: Yeah, I'm using CodeBlocks.
But I like a lot eclipse and wont to use it

Comment: Eclipse is a very bad IDE in my opinion, I never liked it, it's too bloated, CodeBlocks is Ok, but geany is so simple and fast.... After a long experience trying many different possible IDE's I've learned something, don't use a complicated IDE, use a text editor and Makefiles, that's all. A can recommend qtcreator too, but it has poor support for c. And eclipse, only if you are doing Java development.